# How do I create high quality images for Swift Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I create high quality images with sharp edges in programs like Photoshop that will look high quality on any device for iOS Sprite Kit?

If I create an image in Photoshop with 300dpi and then put them into an SKSpriteNode in Sprite Kit, they seem to have blurry edges, when I would like them to be sharp and clean edges.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not sprite-kits fault, just keep making the image larger when you create it in Photoshop

Comment: I think this question was marked as a duplicate in error. The answer in the link does not address the OP's question.